# Spring autowired config gets NullPointerException after using a route with JAVA DSL

Tags: java, spring, maven, apache-camel

Let me start by saying that i havent done any New in my classes except for the camel route builder which is not relevant for this particular question.
I have a maven application, and I want to expose my api by camel route.
In addition I have a properties file which inject the properties by spring.
but when i use main.addRouteBuilder(new Route()) i don't know why the @Autowired annotation is return null.

This is my application context (camel-context)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring 
http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.my.project.service"/>
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:myService.prop"/>
```

This is my main

```
    public class MainApp {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    MainApp mainApp = new MainApp();
    mainApp.startService();
}

private static void startService() throws Exception {

    try {
        AppLogger.debug("Starting Camel with Spring");

        Main main = new Main();
        main.setApplicationContextUri("classpath:camel-context.xml");
        main.addRouteBuilder(new DeleteReportRoute());
        main.run();

        AppLogger.debug("Camel with Spring was succesefully started");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        AppLogger.error("Failed to initialize Camel with Spring);
    }
}
```

this is my config class , and everything is injected as expected.

```
    @Configuration()
@PropertySource("classpath:myService.prop")
public class MyConfig {

private Integer port;

private String host;

private String contextName;

public int getPort() { return port; }

public String getHost() {
    return host;
}

public String getContextName() {
    return contextName;
}

public MyConfig() { }

@Value("${myService.port:8888}")
public void setPort(int port) {
    this.port = port;
}

@Value("${myService.host:localhost}")
public void setHost(String host) {
    this.host = host;
}

@Value("${myService.contextPathName:myservice}")
public void setContextName(String contextName) {
    this.contextName = contextName;
}
}
```

this is my route class

```
@Component() 
public class DeleteReportRoute extends RouteBuilder {

@Autowired
public MyConfig conf; // <----------------- this is return null and i don't know why :(

/**
 * Let's configure the Camel routing rules using Java code...
 */
@Override
public void configure() {
    int port = conf.getPort();
    String contextName = conf.getContextName();

    restConfiguration().component("jetty").host("0.0.0.0").port(port).contextPath(contextName).bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);

    rest("{tvchannel}/{tvprogram}").post("/report").to("direct:deleteReport");

    from("direct:deleteReport")
            .bean("messageHandler", "process")
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(200))
            .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("text/plain"));
}
}
```

note that the all of the packages are under the context:component-scan
and i always get a nullPointerException for my config obj.